# gcc ошибка при выводе float в консоль

Tags: gcc

Имеется очень старая машина Celeron D 347 + Win7 32b + gcc v.11.2

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float num = 1.7;
    std::cout << num;
}
// g++.exe -s main.cpp -o main
```

Данный код прекрасно компилируется в exe, но при запуске выводит виндошное окно, мол работу прекращаем - "Искать решение проблемы в интернете", "Закрыть программу", "Отладить программу". В консоль никакие сообщения не выводятся. При этом float можно объявлять, можно с ними производить арифметические операции и  всё будет нормально, ошибка выскакивает только при попытке вывести float (только с float и double, с int всё нормально) в консоль, при попытке ввести float (std::cin), а также при конвертации в строку std::to_string(). Почему?

ps: Пробовал всевозможные варианты с ключами -march и -mfpmath, не помогло.

pps: Если использовать gcc 8.01, то такой ошибки не наблюдается.

Comment: если это не ошибка компилятора (ну всякое бывает), то лучше взять подходящий отладчик (gdb, студия, x64dbg) и посмотреть, где именно оно упало. А там будет ясно.

Comment: imho не стоит использовать новые версии комптлятора со старыми ОС и железом (вряд ли можно рассчитывать, что их (новые версии) хоть как-то протестировали в старом окружении)